# When are “les”, “des”, etc used or not used?

Tags: grammaire, articles

I couldn't find an answer to this question despite searching, however, I'm sure it must have been asked before!

I would like to know when to use *le/la/les*, *du/de/des*, etc. and when not to use them.

I am using Duolingo to learn French and it has a phrase for translation: *Haricots et du pain* - Beans and bread. Why isn't it *Les haricots et du pain* or *Des haricots et du pain*? My understanding is that *des*, *du*, etc. mean something like "some", so "Beans and bread" usually means the same as "Some beans and some bread" *I eat ~*, *He has ~* but not *~ are food*.

I am finding it difficult to remember to add *les*, *des*, etc. where there is no word at all used in the English phrase. *I like strawberries* - *J'aime les fraises* is something like "I like **all** strawberries", whereas *I am eating strawberries* - *Je mange des fraises* is something like "I am eating **some** strawberries".

However, my understanding seems to be imperfect. Sometimes *des* seems to make more sense but *les* is correct or vice versa. How can I remember which one to use? And why does *haricots* have neither?

---

### EDIT

I was just asked to translate *You sell shoes* so I said *Vous vendez les chaussures*. The app said it was wrong and I should have said *Vous vendez **des** chaussures*. I was following the pattern of *J'aime les fraises*. I might say *You are selling **some** shoes* but I wouldn't say *You sell **some** shoes* as in English it indicates habitual activity and *some* doesn't mean the same thing. I would only say it if you are selling different things and only some of them are shoes and I wanted to emphasise the difference. *You sell some shoes and some clothes*. So why can I say *J'aime **les** fraises* but not *Vous vendez **les** chaussures*?

---

Why does *Il connaît les femmes* translate to *He knows women* (in general)? He obviously can't know **all** women, so why isn't the English phrase *He knows the women* (some specific women) or the French phrase *Il connaît des femmes* (He knows some unspecified women)? If the meaning was *He knows what women are like* or *He knows the nature of women* would it be better to say *Il sait les femmes*?

*les* and *des* are still not making sense to me!

Comment: Les is definite, des is indefinite.

Comment: French has a "plural indefinite article - des" which English does not. It might throw English speakers off since suddenly you need a word in place where English would have none

Comment: I’ve read through all the stuff about de de la du, des etc and I’m even more confused. To be frank in this regard to me, French seems unnecessarily complicated and archaic. It rather puts me off continuing to battle to speak it. I have a daughter & Granddaughters living in Montreal hence my trying to relearn French. English speakers are under attack in Quebec, or so it seems.

Answer (score 9):

Well, this is a tricky one for sure.

Let's start at the beginning. There are 3 categories of article in French.

**First come the definite articles:**

- *Masculine singular*: le, l', du, au
- *Feminine singular*: la, l'
- *Plural*: les, aux, des

You use them when what you're talking about is defined, both the speaker and the listener know the object defined. So it would be the equivalent of `this/that` in English. It is also used for the possessive form, when the belonging is obvious, like "My hand hurts" would be translated to "J'ai mal à la main".

In the shoes example, in the case you want the red shiny shoes you found, you'll ask the vendor "Do you sell the shoes?" then in French "Vendez-vous *les* chaussures ?". Because you're talking about those particular shoes.

**Second are the indefinite articles:**

- *Masculine singular*: un
- *Feminine singular*: une
- *Plural*: des

You use them when what you're talking about is undefined, or can't be defined. It can also be used for emphasis.

Still with the shoes, if you want to ask if the store sells any shoes you'll say "Vendez-vous *des* chaussures?".

For emphasis I'll give you an example. "He is *so* stupid" could be said "Il est *d'un* bête".

**The last one is the partitive article:**

- du, de la, des

It used for what can not be quantified, like bread. Basically it's `some` in English.

**The strawberries singularity**

So, what's up with the strawberries? It's cool to have defined all the articles, but it might not help us to get what is happening in your example.

> — Hey, what are you doing?
>
> — I'm eating strawberries.

In this case, you're eating any strawberries, so you will use "des".

> — Hey, what are you doing?
>
> — I'm eating the last strawberries.

In this case, you're not eating any strawberries, you're eating the last one, damn you! So you'll use "les".

> — Hey, what's you favorite fruit?
>
> — It's strawberries.

Here comes the realm of liking, and yes you were right, liking is kind of a particular case somehow but not really if you think about it. You're asking what kind of fruit you love, and thus it is a defined kind. Therefore you'll use "les", because you're referring to all the strawberries, you love them all as a unique kind of fruit, not some undefined part of them.

**The des grey area**

You must have noticed it. Why *des* is everywhere?

The reason is simple, for the first category it is *des* is the contraction of *de les*. For example "She is the kids' nanny" would be said "Elle est la nourrice des enfants". For the second category, it is really *des*. And for the third category, *des* is actually used for some particular words like for bread you'll use *du* and for spinach you'll use *des*.

I hope I helped you to understand this French nonsense.
Tell me if there is some part you don't get so I can explain more.

Comment: Thank you! _Un/une_ are easy to understand as they work much the same way as _a(n)_ does in English. I also understand when _des_, etc. mean roughly _of the_. It's when they mean _some_ that I'm having trouble with. I liked your use of humour too! I'm looking for a way of correctly choosing _les_ or _des_ in under a second that will make sense to me as a native English speaker! It doesn't have to be perfect, just some general rule that works most of the time. I can remember any exceptions that crop up.

Comment: Well for the general rule that works most of the time, you should follow: If the object is definite, you use *les* if it's undefined, you use *des*.

Comment: The exception when you use *des* instead of *les*, is when you have *de les*, you should replace them by *des*. Like in my example "the kid's nanny", it's the nanny *of the* kids. In french the possessive form *of* is translated by *de*, so you fall in the *de les* rule.

Answer (score 3):

TO answer the specific query: "*So why can I say **J'aime les fraises** but not **Vous vendez les chaussures**?*"

I see the distinction between *les* and *des* a bit differently from you:

**les** implies "all", "the totality", so «*J'aime les fraises*» means that you like all strawberries.  The whole, all-encompasing category including their platonic ideal.

**des** implies a subset, some specific members of the category, so «*J'aime des fraises*» suggests that you like some particular ones on occasion.

Consequently *Vous vendez les chaussures* suggests that he/she is the seller of all the shoes.

Comment: I can see that it's unlikely that a single person would sell **all** shoes, but I also don't like **all** strawberries. Some are under-ripe and crunchy, some are overripe and squishy, some are ripe but flavourless, etc. I'm looking for a way of intuitively understanding which one to use. Does it depend on the verb? So _vendre_ uses _des_, _aimer_ uses _les_, etc? Is this something where in the end I will have to remember which one to use on a case by case basis? If you show me the correct one I can easily adapt my understanding to that example but I still can't pick the right one beforehand.

Comment: No, it doesn't depend on the verb. When you say "I like strawberries" in English it suggests that you like all of them, but unless we're philosophical pedants we understand that you don't actually mean that.  In French you need to be a little more precise.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JPfVGotIQI

Comment: Is it to do with whether the sentence makes sense in continuous aspect? You wouldn't say _I am liking strawberries_ but you could say _You are selling shoes_. I think the problem for me is that _the_ can mean _this/that/these/those_ in some situations. _Can you see the shoes?_ is virtually equivalent to _Can you see these/those shoes?_ which is definitely not the same as _Can you see all shoes?_

Comment: @CJDennis To take your specific example, none of the following make sense to me "I am liking strawberries" / "I am liking some strawberries" / "I am liking the strawberries".

Comment: That was what I was asking, is because none of the sentences starting _I am liking..._ make sense why you would only use _J'aime les..._?

Answer (score 1):

Il y a un certain nombre de cas en français  où l'article est omis:
L'article est habituellement absent devant :

```
- l' apposition : Sa mère, femme remarquable...
- l'attribut : Son fils est médecin.
- le nom en apostrophe : Compagnons, jurons de ne jamais nous rendre.
- certains compléments de noms : Une maison de bois.(et non du bois) Un esprit de synthèse, (et non un esprit de la synthèse) etc.
- devant les noms de jours et de mois s'ils ne sont pas accompagnés d'un élément subordonné : Nous nous verrons lundi.
- devant "minuit" et "midi" : Nous nous verrons à midi.
- devant des noms faisant partie d'une énumération dynamique : Livres, cahiers, stylos volaient à travers la classe.
- avec de nombreuses expressions figées : Crier victoire. Avoir peur. Perdre patience, etc.
- dans le style proverbial : Pierre qui roule n'amasse pas mousse.
- devant les noms qui se désignent eux-mêmes et dans les inscriptions : Axe vient du latin "axis" et signifie proprement "essieu. Voiture à vendre.
```

http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/manuels/ART_OMIS.htm

Answer (score 0):

Le, la and les are used to identify something that is known and unique.

e. g: le cahier.

Un, une and des are used to identify somthing that is not known and not unique. 
e. g: J'ai une voiture.

Du,  de la are used to identify a quantity.
e. g: il a mange' du pain.

In the example above,  it should be: Des haricots et du pain.

In fact, this is how it is written in the doulingo official site:
https://www.duolingo.com/comment/310405

Comment: I am using the iPad app. From one of the comments by Debra.a.ke it appears that the online comment used to say "Haricots..." but has been changed to "Des haricots..."