# Which one is correct, "les légumes" or "des légumes" ?

Tags: articles

I am wondering when I should use "*des*" and "*les*". I know the grammatical point about using "*articles definis*" but I see different sentences on the Internet which made me confused.

Example:

> *Comment confire des légumes ?*
>
> *Braiser des légumes.*
>
> *Cuisinez les légumes.*
>
> *Comment blanchir les légumes ?*

Is it correct to say:

> *Je prépare des légumes frais pour cette salade ?*

Answer (score 5):

"Je mange **des** légumes." means : I eat vegetables. You don't know which are the vegetables. It is "**indéfini**".

"Je mange **les** légumes" would be equivalent to : I eat *the* vegetables. You know that you eat these vegetables. It is "**défini**".

Example : Je mange des légumes tous les jours. Mais aujourd'hui, j'ai mangé les légumes du jardin.

Answer (score 3):

This question was already asked a couple of times, [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13333/when-are-les-des-etc-used-or-not-used?rq=1) and [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19750/correct-use-of-les-and-des?rq=1) for example, although no answer was accepted.

Both *des* and *les* can be used in your sentences.

> *Comment xxxx des légumes ?*

means

> How to xxxx vegetables ? (any kind of them)

while

> *Comment xxxx les légumes ?*

means

> How to xxxx the vegetables ?

with *xxxx* being one of the verbs of your examples (*confire, braiser, cuisiner, blanchir, préparer...*).

Here the meaning might be identical to the previous form, when **the** vegetables is representing "the vegetables in general" but it might also means "the vegetables that we are talking about, the vegetables I need to cook". The context should help figuring out which meaning is intended.

In the last sentence:

> *Je prépare des légumes frais pour cette salade*

You tell you are using some fresh vegetables to make this salad while in:

> *Je prépare les légumes frais pour cette salade*

you tell you use the fresh vegetables (all the ones that are already here) to make the salad.

Comment: Which sentence?

Comment: @jilliagre If I continue the sentence with "tel que", then which form would be correct? je prépare des(les) légumes frais tel que le concombre, le tomate et les petit pois pour cette salade. The nouns after "tel que" must be défini or not?

Comment: They might be definite *Je prépare les / des légumes frais tels que le concombre, **la** tomate et les petit**s** pois* or indefinite *Je prépare des légumes frais tels qu'un concombre, une tomate ou des petits pois* or partitive *Je prépare les / des légumes frais tels que du concombre, de la tomate et des petits pois*. The first option sounds more natural.